# Bug when trying to fetch data from node.js api to flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter

I have searched for a solution but couldn't find any, basically when I search for an account inside the app it shows up and looking fine but when I press it to get to the profile details screen it keeps loading and it seems to never get the data.

Below is the code  for the response

```
import 'dart:convert';

ResponseUserSearch responseUserSearchFromJson(String str) => ResponseUserSearch.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String responseUserSearchToJson(ResponseUserSearch data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class ResponseUserSearch {

    ResponseUserSearch({
        required this.resp,
        required this.message, 
        required this.anotherUser,
        required this.analytics,
        required this.postsUser,
        required this.isFriend,
        required this.isPendingFollowers
    });

    bool resp;
    String message;
    AnotherUser anotherUser;
    Analytics analytics;
    List<PostsUser> postsUser;
    int isFriend;
    int isPendingFollowers;

    factory ResponseUserSearch.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ResponseUserSearch(
        resp: json["resp"],
        message: json["message"],
        anotherUser: AnotherUser.fromJson(json["anotherUser"]),
        analytics: Analytics.fromJson(json["analytics"]),
        postsUser: List<PostsUser>.from(json["postsUser"].map((x) => PostsUser.fromJson(x))),
        isFriend: json["is_friend"],
        isPendingFollowers: json["isPendingFollowers"]
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "resp": resp,
        "message": message,
        "anotherUser": anotherUser.toJson(),
        "analytics": analytics.toJson(),
        "postsUser": List<dynamic>.from(postsUser.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "is_friend": isFriend,
        "isPendingFollowers": isPendingFollowers
    };
}

class Analytics {
    Analytics({
        required this.posters,
        required this.friends,
        required this.followers,
    });

    int posters;
    int friends;
    int followers;

    factory Analytics.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Analytics(
        posters: json["posters"],
        friends: json["friends"],
        followers: json["followers"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "posters": posters,
        "friends": friends,
        "followers": followers,
    };
}

class AnotherUser {
    AnotherUser({
        required this.uid,
        required this.fullname,
        required this.phone,
        required this.image,
        required this.cover,
        required this.birthdayDate,
        required this.createdAt,
        required this.username,
        required this.description,
        required this.isPrivate,
        required this.email,
    });

    String uid;
    String fullname;
    String phone;
    String image;
    String cover;
    dynamic birthdayDate;
    DateTime createdAt;
    String username;
    String description;
    int isPrivate;
    String email;

    factory AnotherUser.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => AnotherUser(
        uid: json["uid"],
        fullname: json["fullname"],
        phone: json["phone"] ?? '',
        image: json["image"] ?? '',
        cover: json["cover"] ?? '',
        birthdayDate: DateTime.parse(json["birthday_date"] ?? '2021-10-22T20:17:53'),
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"] ?? '2021-10-22T20:17:53'),
        username: json["username"],
        description: json["description"] ?? '',
        isPrivate: json["is_private"],
        email: json["email"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "uid": uid,
        "fullname": fullname,
        "phone": phone,
        "image": image,
        "cover": cover,
        "birthday_date": birthdayDate,
        "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
        "username": username,
        "description": description,
        "is_private": isPrivate,
        "email": email,
    };
}

class PostsUser {

    PostsUser({
        required this.postUid,
        required this.isComment,
        required this.typePrivacy,
        required this.createdAt,
        required this.images
    });

    String postUid;
    int isComment;
    String typePrivacy;
    DateTime createdAt;
    String images;

    factory PostsUser.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PostsUser(
        postUid: json["post_uid"],
        isComment: json["is_comment"],
        typePrivacy: json["type_privacy"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
        images: json["images"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "post_uid": postUid,
        "is_comment": isComment,
        "type_privacy": typePrivacy,
        "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
        "images": images,
    };
}
```

below is the profile page where I call that data

```
class ProfileAnotherUserPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String idUser;

  const ProfileAnotherUserPage({Key? key, required this.idUser}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProfileAnotherUserPage> createState() => _ProfileAnotherUserPageState();
}


class _ProfileAnotherUserPageState extends State<ProfileAnotherUserPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return BlocListener<UserBloc, UserState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if( state is LoadingFollowingUser ){
          modalLoading(context, 'Duke u ngarkuar...');
        }else if( state is FailureUserState ){
          Navigator.pop(context);
          errorMessageSnack(context, state.error);
        }else if( state is SuccessFollowingUser ){
          Navigator.pop(context);
          setState(() {});
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: FutureBuilder<ResponseUserSearch>(
            future: userService.getAnotherUserById(widget.idUser),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return !snapshot.hasData
              ? const _LoadingDataUser()
              : _BodyUser(responseUserSearch: snapshot.data!);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _BodyUser extends StatelessWidget {

  final ResponseUserSearch responseUserSearch;

  const _BodyUser({ Key? key, required this.responseUserSearch  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return ListView(
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      children: [

          _CoverAndProfile(user: responseUserSearch.anotherUser),
          const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          _UsernameAndDescription(user: responseUserSearch.anotherUser),
          const SizedBox(height: 30.0),
          _PostAndFollowingAndFollowers(analytics: responseUserSearch.analytics),
          const SizedBox(height: 30.0),
          _BtnFollowAndMessage(
            isFriend: responseUserSearch.isFriend, 
            uidUser: responseUserSearch.anotherUser.uid,
            isPendingFollowers: responseUserSearch.isPendingFollowers,
            username: responseUserSearch.anotherUser.username,
            avatar: responseUserSearch.anotherUser.image,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
            height: 46,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const Icon(Icons.grid_on_rounded, size: 30),
                const SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                Container(
                  height: 1,
                  color: Colors.grey[300],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 5.0),
          _ListFotosAnotherProfile(
            posts: responseUserSearch.postsUser, 
            isPrivate: responseUserSearch.anotherUser.isPrivate,
            isFriend: responseUserSearch.isFriend,
          ),

      ],
    );
  }
}
```

below is the backend code for this particular problem

```
export const getAnotherUserById = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> => {

    try {

        const conn = await connect();

        const [ userdb ] = await conn.query<RowDataPacket[]>(`CALL SP_GET_USER_BY_ID(?);`, [ req.params.idUser ]);

        const posters = await conn.query<RowDataPacket[]>(' SELECT COUNT(person_uid) AS posters FROM posts WHERE person_uid = ?', [req.params.idUser]);
        const friends = await conn.query<RowDataPacket[]>('SELECT COUNT(person_uid) AS friends FROM friends WHERE person_uid = ?', [req.params.idUser]);
        const followers = await conn.query<RowDataPacket[]>('SELECT COUNT(person_uid) AS followers FROM followers WHERE person_uid = ?', [req.params.idUser]);
        const posts = await conn.query<RowDataPacket[]>(`CALL SP_GET_POST_BY_IDPERSON(?);`, [req.params.idUser]);
        const isFollowing = await conn.query<RowDataPacket[]>('CALL SP_IS_FRIEND(?,?);', [req.idPerson, req.params.idUser]);
        const isPendingFollowers = await conn.query<RowDataPacket[]>(`CALL SP_IS_PENDING_FOLLOWER(?,?)`, [ req.params.idUser, req.idPerson ]);

        conn.end();

        return res.json({
            resp: true,
            message: 'Get Another User by id',
            anotherUser: userdb[0][0],
            analytics: {
                'posters' : posters[0][0].posters,
                'friends' : friends[0][0].friends,
                'followers': followers[0][0].followers
            },
            postsUser: posts[0][0],
            is_friend: isFollowing[0][0][0].is_friend,
            isPendingFollowers: isPendingFollowers[0][0][0].is_pending_follower
        });

    } catch(err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            resp: false,
            message: err
        });
    }

}
```

This is the getAnotherUserById function

```
Future<ResponseUserSearch> getAnotherUserById(String idUser) async {

    final token = await secureStorage.readToken();

    final resp = await http.get(Uri.parse('${URLS.urlApi}/user/get-another-user-by-id/'+ idUser),
      headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'xxx-token': token! }
    );

    return ResponseUserSearch.fromJson(jsonDecode(resp.body));
  }
```

Comment: You need to be able to isolate the problem to either server or client side. it's completely impractical to solve it with indirect clues

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do my best next time. I believe the problem is on client side.